# How to I incorporate multithreading into IDA* search algorithm?

Tags: java, multithreading, solver, rubiks-cube, iterative-deepening

I have implemented Korf’s Algorithm (A solving algorithm for the Rubik’s cube that always produced optimal solutions).
If a solution requires between 15-20 moves, it can take over a solid day for the computer to generate, test and evaluate each node.

My solution is to spread out this workload over several threads... I’m not too experienced with threading although I have done it before for different projects.

Does anyone know how I could implement this in Java?

Any advice, recommendations and ideas are much welcome.

Thank you

Comment: You might take a look at this repo: https://github.com/christopherburke/rubik_opt  I, too, implemented Korf's and wrote about it on Medium.  That person contacted me on Medium and Github and told me that he'd implemented a multi-threaded version in cython.  I haven't looked at the code exhaustively, but it looks pretty cool and seems to do what you want.